# In how many conferences should I serve as PC member?

Tags: peer-review

Three months ago, I served as a PC (=Program Committee) member in a top conference in my field (CS). Now, I was offered to serve as a PC member in another top conference.
Although I found this job quite fun, I still wonder, in how many conferences "should" I be a PC each year? ("should" in quotes, since there is no formal obligation).

Comment: What's "PC", you should explain abbreviations...

Comment: "Should" depends on your goals: is this for etiquette? getting tenure? enhancing your reputation? staying on top of advances in the field?

Comment: @DSVA PC = Program Committee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no right answer here. It’s a function of the time you have available to do service duties, as well as the benefits to you of helping out. However, it is a significant time commitment, so it’s probably not necessary to do it more than a few times a year. But whether the right answer is one, two, three, or more is a question only you can answer.